# TeeChart bottom axis labels are cut off in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, teechart

I'm building an iOS app (unified) using Xamarin. I'm also using TeeCharts. I have a very simple bar chart whose bottom axis labels are rotated by 90 degrees (vertical labels). The bottom axis shows dates (10 days, starting from today). I've also set the date format to "MM/dd".

Here's my code:

```
private void CreateChartUI()
    {
        CGColor textColor = UIColor.Black.CGColor;

        this.Chart.Aspect.View3D = false;
        this.Chart.Header.Text = String.Empty;
        this.Chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Manual;
        this.Chart.Zoom.Active = false;
        this.Chart.Zoom.Allow = false;
        this.Chart.Panning.Allow = ScrollModes.None;
        this.Chart.Legend.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Header.Text = "Test";

        // Walls
        this.Chart.Walls.Back.Pen.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Walls.Back.Gradient.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Walls.Back.Color = UIColor.Gray.CGColor;

        // Left axis
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.AxisPen.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Grid.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Ticks.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.MinorTicks.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.MinorGrid.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Grid.Style = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.DashStyle.Solid;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Grid.Color = UIColor.White.CGColor;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Grid.Width = 2;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.Color = textColor;
        this.Chart.Axes.Left.MaximumOffset = 30;

        // Bottom axis
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.AxisPen.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.Ticks.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.MinorTicks.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.MinorGrid.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90;
        this.Chart.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Color = textColor;

        // series
        Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar testSeries = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar() { VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Left };
        testSeries.Marks.Visible = false;
        testSeries.Color = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
        testSeries.XValues.DateTime = true;
        testSeries.BarWidthPercent = 100 * (int) (float)UIKit.UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale;
        testSeries.SideMargins = true;
        this.Chart.Series.Add(testSeries);
    }
```

The result is this:

[image: chart]

As you can see, the labels of the bottom axis are cut off. I'm using the latest TeeChart version (4.15.1.19).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you're correct, it's a bug which has already been fixed. It will be included into the next maintenance release which will be availble at the Xamarin Store and also on our web site at the customers download page.

Thanks!

Josep

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an estimated release date? We need this fix as soon as possible...

Comment: @vbm we expect it to be published during this week.

Comment: @Narcís Calvet I downloaded the latest version but I'm still seeing the same issue...

Comment: @vbm yes, you are right. I could reproduce the problem here again. We will investigate it and get back to you ASAP. Many apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @vbm for completeness, I added it to our bug list: http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1223